# How to increment rows only using the ROW() function and an Increment value?

Tags: excel, function, formula

I have searched all over but have not found an answer to this particular question. I have spent hours on this and have not come up with a solution.

[image: Increment Problem]

What formula will yield the results shown in the yellow region, column K, that only uses the ROW() function and the cell reference (H18) which contains the Increment Value in the formula?

For example: the desired results shown in column K should match the values in the green area in column G using the Increment value of 5.

When the Increment value is later changed to 6, the results should match the values in Column H, and so on...

Note: The formula cannot use references to any other cells except itself. The initial formula will entered in cell K1 and then be copied downwards to yield results as shown in the yellow region.

In addition, this should be a formula type answer and not a VBA solution.

Two Failed example formulas:
=inc*(ROW()-1), and =(row+inc)
where defined names: inc = $H$18 and row = ROW()-1

BTW... I am using Excel 2000

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula should be:

`=1 + (ROW()-1)*inc`

Comment: Thank you so much Slothario. I tested it for all 7 columns and it works well.